# What are the lyrics and translation for the Nazgûl theme music?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, music, translation

In the *Lord of the Rings* trilogy we often hear the Nazgûl theme music:

What are the lyrics and translation for the words the choir sings repeatedly throughout the films?

Answer (score 8):

[Dungeons and Dragons Online](http://www.ddo.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-290402.html) gives this translation for the Black Rider:

> Nebabitham Maganane  Netabdam daurad  Nepam ned abarat-aglar  ido
>   Nidir nenakham  Bari 'n Katharad
>
> 'We deny our maker.  We cling to the darkness.  We grasp for ourselves
>   power and glory.  Now we come, the Nine,  Lords of Eternal Life.

From [Lyrics Translate](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/nazg%C3%BBl-nazgul.html#ixzz3tcfxa06k):

> The Nazgûl
>
> Ristais dúath Nerchennin o chuil Coll am na waewath goeyl Tellin i
>   Neder Gurth renia Meditha han phan Meditha ardhon
>
> The Nazgul
>
> Shreds of shadow Torn from life Borne aloft By fell winds. The Nine
>   have come Death has taken wing. He will eat it all Eat all the world.

Also, here's a video with subtitles

and another one

Comment: I only add this because I feel it is a more definitive source:

The Music of The Lord of the Rings by Douglas Adams - which is a comprehensive collaboration with Howard Shore containing critical analysis of all three films. Page 313

Comment: Per *The Annotated Score*, the DDO translation is the more correct one. The title of the song is "The Revelation of the Ringwraiths", and the translation is "We renounce our Maker. We cleave to the darkness. We take unto ourselves the power and glory. Behold! We are the Nine, the Lords of Unending Life."

Comment: Bummer that the lyrics are in Sindarin, but I guess the Black Speech wasn't really designed for singing...

Comment: @MikeHarris The lyrics are actually in Adunaic. </nerd>

Comment: Both video links are dead

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question, we need the lyrics of the poem written for the movie by Philippa Boyens (and translated to Adûnaic by David Salo); [*The Revelation of the Ringwraiths*](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Revelation_of_the_Ringwraiths):

> **Adûnaic:**
>
> Nêbâbîtham Magânanê
>   Nêtabdam dâur-ad
>   Nêpâm nêd abârat-aglar
>   îdô Nidir nênâkham
>   Bârî’n Katharâd
>
> **English:**
>
> We renounce our Maker
>   We cleave to the darkness
>   We take unto ourselves the power and glory
>   Behold! We are the Nine
>   The Lords of Unending Life.
>
> <sub><sup>[Fellowship of the Ring Annotated Scores](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/pdf/fotr_annotated_score_2.pdf).</sup></sub>

This poem is not used directly on the soundtrack but fractions of it appear at many places. You can find them [here](http://www.amagpiesnest.com/source_songs/FOTR/SSrevelation_of_the_ringwraith.htm).

Comment: If you're going to quote things, don't forget to use > quote tags to show that they're taken directly from elsewhere.

Comment: Also, it's not considered "nice" to spend a large chunk of your answer explaining why someone else's answer is worse than yours.